# How to give label the value from an array element?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am new to Swift and I am creating a survey application in which the user data gets saved throughout.

In the code below the search button refers to the retrieve function. I created a retrieve function and wanted the saved information to appear on the label. I need help to give the label the value of an element in my array. So basically once the retrieve button has been clicked it returns the saved information to the label.

```
  @IBAction func searchButton(_ sender: Any) {
        retrieveData()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var statusLabel: UILabel!


// These are the labels that I have made. 

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


func retrieveData() {

        //As we know that container is set up in the AppDelegates so we need to refer that container.
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }

        //We need to create a context from this container
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        //Prepare the request of type NSFetchRequest  for the entity
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Data")

        fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id = %@", idText.text!)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor.init(key: "id", ascending: false)]
        //

        do {
            let result = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
                //print(data.value(forKey: "id")!)
                idText.text = data.value(forKey:"id") as? String
            }

            statusLabel.text = "Data found"
            showidLabel.text = // I WANT TO ASSIGN THE SAVED VALUE TO THIS LABEL
        } catch {

            print("Failed")
        }
    }
```

Comment: which element of the array you wanna present in the `UILabel` text?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the text of the label to the text that you want to show. Either way, you need to define and have access to the label in your UIViewcontroller. I think that may be where you are missing it. You only have statusLabel with an outlet.

So, you can make a function that updates the value of your label and pass the value that you want it to be.

Or, if you only update the Label text when you are also doing something else, pass that value to the label text.

```
MyLabel.text = value
```

If your value is in an array and you know the id, you will say:

```
MyLabel.text = array[id]
```